# Arch | SSH fail on reboot

Tags: archlinux, ssh, failure

I have a really weird problem with my Raspberry Pi.

It runs correctly when I reboot it via the command `reboot`.

After this it starts up and doesn't answer any network request. I have tried `ssh`, `httpd`, `samba` and `ping`. If I kill it by removing the power plug and restarting it it works as expected.

The other side is if I'm rebooting it via `reboot -f` it starts the services as it should and I can connect to the `ssh` server as normal.

**Any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix it?**

**Solution:** The error is based on `dhcpcd` which is not shutting down correctly. Adding the line `DHClient  = 'yes'` in the `/etc/network.d/ethernet-eth0`-file and installing the package `dhclient` fixed it. `systemctl disable dcpcd@eth0` should be executed for not getting the error again.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: What(if any) messages are spawned during its reboot? Will have to connect to display to observe.

Comment: Nope it's not spawning any message at reboot. Ethernet is connected as after a normal boot (or forced reboot).

Comment: If you ask a question and later find the answer, go ahead and post it as a solution below. That way it doesn't look like an unanswered question that no one can respond to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution to the problem with the services failing to start:

**Solution**: The error is based on dhcpcd which is not shutting down correctly. Adding the line `DHClient = 'yes'` in the `/etc/network.d/ethernet-eth0`-file and installing the package `dhclient` fixed it. `systemctl disable dcpcd@eth0` should be executed for not getting the error again.